Involuntary repeat key in ubuntu 24.04 (no hardware issue)
I am using Ubuntu 24.04, with kernel 6.8.0-40-generic on a thinkpad-e14. Once in a while I see that arrow-down-key or enter-key is pressed involuntarily. These are the reasons I don't think this is a hardware problem

I ran evtest. When I see the arrow-down-key was in action infinitely. I checked the evtest-logs, and didn't find any KEY_DOWN event at that time. Although about ~1 minute before this incident, there were lots of voluntary KEY_DOWN 2 (repeat) on some other window that I did.
This also happens when I am connected to a USB-keyboard, and the laptop is untouched for multiple hours.

These are the things that I have tried:

In my accessiblity, repeat keys are on. If I switch off repeat-keys, this issue DOES NOT occur. I had tried with repeat keys off for a few days to make sure of this.
I checked sticky-keys was off as per another post Involuntary key repeat in Ubuntu 16.04
I switched to XOrg (from Wayland) for a day, and I still see the issue (with repeat-keys ON).

Not using repeat keys is a big pain for me. What actions can I take? Please help!

I get the same behaviour on ubuntu 24 Lenovo thinkpad L15, it does not seem to be a hardware issue as the key that seems to be kept pressed is different everytime.  It does happen once every 1-3 days. Also happens on when working on different software/programs. Switching repeat keys helps but than key repeat is also useful.
